# what it signifies if a symbol is mentioned in symtab but not in dynsym of readelf output?

Tags: compilation, linker, readelf

I have a shared library named libtest.so. I was analyzing the readelf output of this .so to solve `undefined reference to _invalid_parameter()`. The readelf output shows _invalid_parameter UND in .symtab section but no mention of it in .dynsym section.

**Could somebody please explain what it signifies to have a symbol mentioned in .symtab section but not in .dynsym section?**

libtest.so is dynamically linking to few other shared libraries but none of them is providing definition for _invalid_parameter but still linking is passing. Any idea, **how**?

Comment: `how?` - the linker sees that `_invalid_parameter` is never called from nowhere, so it optimizes it out.

Comment: if you mean to say it removes the dead code (unused code), _invalid_parameter should not be appeared in .symtab as well, no?